# Extra space in jquery dropdown navbar

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

```
nav {float:left;position: relative;}
nav ul {text-align:center;}
nav ul li {float:left;display:inline;}
nav ul li:hover {background:#E6E6E6;}
nav ul li a {display:block;padding:15px 25px;color:#444;}
nav ul li ul {display:block;position:absolute;width:110px;background:#FFF;}
nav ul li ul li {width:110px;}
nav ul li ul li a {display:block;padding:15px 10px;color:#444;}
nav ul li ul li:hover a {background:#F7F7F7;}
nav ul li ul.fallback {display:none;}
nav ul li:hover ul.fallback {display:block;}

<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <ul class="fallback">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <ul class="fallback">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nkqC8/

So im trying to implement a dropdown nav bar on my new design, but there is this extra space on the left side. I need to remove that otherwise I can't use my fontawesome icons on the navigation menu. So any help with that? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update line 2 of css to this:

```
nav ul {text-align:center; padding: 0; }
```

ul elements have padding left on by default.

Comment: And better even still, remove padding and margin on all objects within your HTML. I bet your code will look different on IE vs FF - removing padding and margin will level the playing field in all browsers.

Comment: [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) is a good limited css reset to use